# How to Limit Input to Numbers Only

Tags: c++, validation, input, numbers, character

I recently created a program that will create a math problem based on the user input.  By entering either 1-4 the program can generate a problem or the user can quit by entering 5.  The only problem I am having is that when I enter a character the program goes into an infinite loop.  What function could I use to check if the input is not a number so I can display an error message?

---

```
//CIS180 Assignment #4
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Declare variables.
    int num1, num2, menuNum;
    int addInput, subInput, multInput, divInput;
    int addAnswer, subAnswer, multAnswer, divAnswer;
    int addSolution, subSolution, multSolution, divSolution;
    srand(time(0));
    //Display menu.
    cout << "Menu" << endl;
    cout << "1. Addition problem" << endl;
    cout << "2. Subtraction problem" << endl;
    cout << "3. Multiplication problem" << endl;
    cout << "4. Division problem" << endl;
    cout << "5. Quit this program" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Enter your choice (1-5): " << endl;
    cin >> menuNum;
    //Loop that will provide math problems when user inputs number.
    while(menuNum != 5)
    {
        //Check if the input is valid.
        while((menuNum < 1) || (menuNum >5))
        {
            cout << "The valid choices are 1, 2, 3 , 4, and 5. Please choose: " << endl;
            cin >> menuNum;
        }
        //Generate two random numbers for addition and display output.
        if(menuNum == 1)
        {
            num1 = rand()%500 + 1;
            num2 = rand()%500 + 1;
            addSolution = num1 + num2;
            cout << setw(5) << right << num1 << endl;
            cout << setw(2) << left << "+" << setw(3) << right << num2 << endl;
            cout << setw(5) << fixed << "-----" << endl;
            cin >> addAnswer;
            //Check if the addition answer input is correct.
            if(addAnswer != addSolution)
                cout << "Sorry, the correct answer is " << addSolution << "." << endl;
            else if(addAnswer == addSolution)
                cout << "Congratulations! That's right." << endl << endl;
        }
        .
            .
            .
```

Comment: Can you narrow the problem down from over 100 lines of code?

Comment: By the way, you don't need to declare all variables at the beginning of your program. Instead, declare them where they're actually used. This way you will still remember that `menuNum` is an `int` and you won't forget to initialize them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, you should detect whether your input attempt was successful: **always** check **after** reading that the read attempt was successful. Next, when you identify that you couldn't read a value you'll need to reset the stream to a good state using `clear()` and you'll need to get rid of any bad characters, e.g., using `ignore()`. Given that the characters were typically entered, i.e., the user had to hit return before the characters were used it is generally reaonable to get of the entire line. For example:

```
for (choice = -1; !(1 <= choice && choice <= 5); ) {
    if (!(std::cin >> choice)) {
         std::cout << "invalid character was added (ignoring the line)\n";
         std::cin.clear();
         std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
}
```

The use of `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` is the way to obtain the magic number which makes `ignore()` as many characters as necessary until a character with the value of its second argument is found.

Answer (score 4):

1. Read a single character
2. If this character is a digit, use it.
3. If this character wasn't a digit, goto 1.

Actually, forget about step 2. Just check whether it was one of the digit characters you actually want (`'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, `'4'`, `'5'`):

```cpp
char choice;

while(cin.get(choice)){
  if(choice == '5')
    break;

  switch(choice){
    default: printWrongCharacterMessage(); break;
    case '1': do1Stuff(); break;
    case '2': do2Stuff(); break;
    case '3': do3Stuff(); break;
    case '4': do4Stuff(); break;    
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution is difficult to extend to two digit choices.  Dietmar Kuhl's solution is better.  Input an integer and test whether it succeeded or not.

Comment: Although I did not specifically use the code you provided, it was very helpful.  I simply declared char menuNum[4] since it will not be used in calculations and changed the rest accordingly, it works perfectly fine now. Thank you!

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: This solution isn't meant to extend to two digit choices. Dietmar's solution is different (and for single-digits a little bit too much in my opinion), and that's why I posted this answer instead of your standard "read, test, clear" routine. Both are valid ;).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [isdigit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) from ctype.h