# C++ First program - Calculator

Tags: c++, switch-statement, case, calculator

Hello I just started learning C++ and Im trying to make a calculator, right now having a fue problems that I simply dont know how to fix in C++.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main() {
int a, b, c, d;

cout << "1. Saskaitiissana(+)" << endl;
cout << "2. atnnemssana(-)" << endl;
cout << "3. daliissana(/)" << endl;
cout << "4. reizinaassana(*)" << endl;

cin >> d;

switch(d){
case 1 :
cout << "ievadiet a un b lai saskaitiitu(+)" << endl;

cin >> a;
cin >> b;
c = a + b;

cout << "The sum of number 1 and number 2 is " << c << "\n" <<endl;
break;


case 2 :
cout << "ievadiet a un b lai atnnemtu(-)" << endl;

cin >> a;
cin >> b;
c = a - b;

cout << c << endl;
break;


case 3 :
cout << "ievadiet a un b lai reizinaatu(*)" << endl;

cin >> a;
cin >> b;
c = a * b;

cout << c << endl;
break;

case 4 :
cout << "ievadiet a un b lai dal'itu(/)" << endl;
cin >> a;
cin >> b;

if(b==0)
{
cout<<"Nulle neder! start over."<<endl;
}

c = a/b;

cout << c << endl;
break;
}



return 0;
}
```

The things I still have to do.
Find the most easy way for the program to use numbers only. Also when I type in a number it can not be "empty space". 
Also how can I make the case after it finish and gives you the result, go back to the begining of start menu? and if I want to exit a program I press esc or 5?

Also with the exit option I was thinking of useing do while "5" is pressed, can that work in c++?

Right now Im most interested on how to check program to use numbers only and have no empty space when adding numbers.

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Regarding limiting the character input to only numbers check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936664/how-to-limit-input-to-numbers-only and http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/21595/

Comment: Please take some time to read the [help]. This is not a general forum for giving broad advice and guidance. We'd like to focus on specific programming problems.

Comment: Improve your code with the links suggested and if you encounter issues post separate questions.

Answer (score 2):

For ignoring non-numeric input you can this piece of code:

```cpp
std::cin >> d;
while(std::cin.fail())
{
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
    std::cout << "Bad entry.  Enter a NUMBER: ";
    std::cin >> d;
}
```

or in C-style:

```cpp
while(scanf("%i",&d)!=1)
{
    fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);
}
```

You can also put your whole bunch of code in a `while` statement to re-run the calculator after one operation.

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account the safe input:

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void SafeDouble (double &d)
{
    while (!(cin >> d))
    {   cin.clear();
        while (cin.get() != '\n');
        cout << "\tIncorrect. Try again\n\t";
    }
    cin.sync();
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{   
        cout << "The simpliest calculator\n";

        double a = 0.,b = 0.;
        cout << "\na = ";
        SafeDouble (a);
        cout << "b = ";
        SafeDouble (b);

        cout << "\nEnter operation sign: +, -, * or /\n";
        char op;
        cin >> op;
        cin.sync(); 

        switch (op)
        {
            case '+':   cout << a << " + " << b << " = " << a + b;
                        break;
            case '-':   cout << a << " - " << b << " = " << a - b;
                        break;
            case '*':   cout << a << " - " << b << " = " << a * b;
                        break;
            case '/':   if (b == 0.0)
                            cout << "Division by zero";
                        else
                            cout << a << " / " << b << " = " << a / b;
                        break;
            default:    cout << "Incorrect operation sign";
        }

        cin.get();
        return 0;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```