# How to accept only numbers in 'cin' (C++ Programming)?

Tags: c++, cin

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <locale>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "English");

    int i, vetor[16];
    for(i = 0; i < 16; i ++) {
        cout << "Input the position: [" << i << "]: ";
        cin  >> vetor[i];
        if(cin.fail()) {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits < streamsize > ::max(), '\n');
            cout << "Please, input only numbers." << endl;
            i --;
            continue;
        }

        if(vetor[i] <= 0) {
            cout << "Insert a non-zero value." << endl;
            i --;
            continue;
        }
    }
    cout << vetor[0];

    return 0;
}
```

And I need to accept only numbers. When I run it and insert `"1"` (or any other number), it goes to the following position, what's correct. When I input `"a"`, it shows me the error and warn me to input only numbers, what's correct too. If I input `"a1"`, the same thing occurs, what's correct. But when I input `"1a"`, it shows me the warning, but the code continues to the next position, and when it executes the last line with the `cout` command above the `return`, it tells me the value is `"1"`, not `"1a"`, because the type of the variable is `int` I believe.

Can someone tells me why does it happen? I need to accept only numbers, and `"1a"` is not a number. How can I filter this and how can I do to when I input `"1a"`, occurs the same thing as I had input `"a"`?

I use DevC++ 5.11.

Comment: And this one too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936664/how-to-limit-input-to-numbers-only

Comment: DevC++ is an IDE. How is that relevant to the question?

Comment: @MrEricSir I don't know, maybe it's a bug, some people told me that it's the worst IDE ever. I just downloaded it because it's free, light and portable.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because `cin` extracts the `1` digit in one pass, and stores that in your array. It stops reading when it encounters the `a` (since that is not a valid character for an integer), and leaves it in the input buffer. It then reads the `a` on the next pass, which causes it to fail because it's not an integer.

What you should do is use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read strings instead. Then you can do any kind of parsing you want. You can use functions from the standard library like [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) if they suit you. Otherwise write your own custom parsing.